# Do app developers have the option to prevent their window from being 'zoomed'?

Tags: dock, window-manager

There's an option in `System Preferences > Dock` where you can double click on the top of a window to make it fit the screen, or what Apple calls 'zoom'.

Is there some way where an app developer can prevent this, while still letting their app window be resized by dragging the edges of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. App developers can set `AppleActionOnDoubleClick` to ‘Maximize’, ‘Minimize’ or ‘None’.